# Possible to reveal parameters in SQL of teiid-command log when query catalog?

Tags: redhat-datavirt

I am trying to debug a tools (black box to me), that is querying the Sys catalog but not getting the metadata that it needs to. While looking into the tepid-command log I find a lot of queries with parameters shown as "?"

Is there a way to reveal what parameter is actually being sent?

Here is an example query, parameter can be seen in the LIKE clause:

sql=SELECT VDBName AS TABLE_CAT, SchemaName AS TABLE_SCHEM, TableName AS TABLE_NAME, Name AS COLUMN_NAME, Length AS DATA_TYPE, ...  WHERE UCASE(SchemaName) LIKE ? ESCAPE '\' AND UCASE(TableName) LIKE ? ESCAPE '\' AND UCASE(Name) LIKE ? ESCAPE '\' AND UCASE(VDBName) LIKE ? ESCAPE '\'  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there currently is a place where parameters are clearly logged.  It is possible to add them to the new event in the command log via an enhancement.